# Travel to New York

Tags: airports, transportation, new-york-city, ewr

We will be traveling to New York City in October. There is a flight into Newark NJ on Southwest; the hotel is near Times Square. Are we able to get into Manhattan from Newark International Airport (EWR)? Should we fly into LaGuardia in order to get from the airport to the hotel?

Comment: LaGuardia would be better unless there is a huge difference in flight prices.

Comment: Regarding which airport to fly into--DO NOT USE LA GUARDIA. Even if it appears closer, due to construction the traffic in and around the airport is absolutely horrible.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question and can be answered without much 'opinion'.

Comment: How mobile are you?  Are you willing to walk up/down some stairs or are you looking for door-to-door transfers?

Comment: I feel as though this question is asking "Is it practical to travel from EWR to Manhattan?"  That question is an opinion question and is not permitted on this forum as phrased.  If you were to rephrase the question as "What are the transportation options from EWR to Manhattan and how do they compare to the transportation options from LaGuardia to Manhattan?" then the question could be answered objectively.  You can then use the provided answers to form an opinion which answers your question of "Is it practical to travel from EWR to Manhattan?"

Comment: @Johns-305: Well, "can we get there from EWR" is a reasonable question and the answer is certainly "yes, there are lots of ways to do it".  "Should we use LGA instead" is opinion-based - my impression is that "which airport is best" is a holy-war question among New Yorkers (although none of them thinks it's a matter of opinion, because each feels that their view is objectively right and all others are objectively wrong).

Answer (score 2):

The distance between Newark and Times Square is longer than between LaGuardia Airport and Times Square, so based on distance, it may be better to fly into LaGuardia. However, it also depends on what time your flight is landing. If it's during the day (non-rush hour) then it probably won't matter which airport since it'll take you about 30 minutes to get to Times Square from each. If cost is a factor, taxi service from LaGuardia is [cheaper](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60763-i5-k6026891-Fly_into_Laguardia_JFK_or_Newark_to_get_to_Manhatten_Quick-New_York_City_New_York.html) than Newark.

As for your second question, you can get to a hotel via nearly all public and private transportation - depending on how well you know the bus/train system. You might be better off just calling a cab.

Comment: If you're not going to use public transit from Newark, I'd recommend a car service over a cab to save a few bucks. A Newark taxi will run you $55 plus tolls and tip to Midtown Manhattan. [Dial7](https://www.dial7.com/), to name one such service, is around $38 plus tolls and tip with [a coupon](https://www.retailmenot.com/view/dial7.com) (a few bucks more during rush hour). Note that tolls out of Newark are around $15.

Comment: The [Newark Airport Express](https://web.coachusa.com/olympia/ss.newarkairport.asp) drops you not [ten minutes](https://goo.gl/maps/9tepmKip2m52) from Times Square. I do not think there's a way to get from LGA to Times Square without a transfer. But the express bus is more expensive than public transit with a transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get from either EWR or LGA to Times Square, as there are several options to get you there. Most people make their decision based on which airport gets them the lowest fare, because of the plethora of ride options into the City.

From EWR you can take AirTrain/NJ Transit into Penn Station, from which Times Square is a short walk or cab ride - depends on how much luggage you're willing to carry half a mile. There are also buses and shuttles that can deposit you near Grand Central and/or Port Authority, which are also a short cab ride/walk to Times Square. Uber, Via, etc. also serve EWR - although these cost more than from LGA.

From LGA, there are shuttles into Manhattan, as well as taxis and other car services. If you are on a budget, you can also take the M60 SBS to the 2/3 at 125th Street, which you can take directly to Times Square/42nd Street.